# Subquery not returning values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query containing a subquery that uses the result of a temporary table in the WHERE statement of the subquery. However, this isn't returning the results I'm expecting. Essentially there is a table EXT_Workpackage that contains values for EXT_Workpackage_ID (Primary Key) and Parent_Workpackage_ID. I am using the Parent_Workpackage_ID to return the Workpackage_Code of the Parent (Workpackages can have multiple Workpackages associated with them).

I will copy the code below:

```
    USE DeltekPIMQA

    select
    pa.EXT_Workpackage_ID,
    pa.Parent_Workpackage_ID [Parent_Workpackage_ID],
    SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),CONVERT(decimal(18,2),ISNULL(h.Hours,0))/60)) [hrs]

    INTO #tempactualhoursb
    FROM 
    EXT_Workpackage wp
    LEFT JOIN exvw_tmshours h on wp.Workpackage_Code=h.wp collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    LEFT JOIN EXT_Workpackage pa on wp.Parent_Workpackage_ID=pa.EXT_Workpackage_ID
    WHERE wp.Project_ID=868
    and pa.Workpackage_Code is not null
    Group by pa.EXT_Workpackage_ID,pa.Workpackage_Code, pa.Parent_Workpackage_ID
    ORDER BY pa.Workpackage_Code


    select
    wp.EXT_Workpackage_ID,
    wp.Workpackage_Code [Code],
    RIGHT(wp.Workpackage_Code,3) [job],
    wp.name [Name],
    wp.Parent_Workpackage_ID [Parent_Workpackage_ID],
    wps.name [Status],
    wps.name [@stato],
   wpc.name [ContractType],
    wpt.name [LeadTrade],
    --PWC.Workpackage_Code,


    CASE
        WHEN WPS.ext_workpackage_status_id not in (3,13) THEN ISNULL(wp.Duration,0)
        ELSE 0
    END
    [SalesBudget],

    --ISNULL(wp.Duration,0) [SalesBudget],





    ISNULL(tah.hrs,0)- ISNULL(wp.Duration,0) [PerformanceVsSales],
    CAST(ISNULL(CONVERT(INT,(tah.hrs- wp.Duration)/NULLIF(wp.duration,0)*100),0) as varchar(16)) + '%' [Percent],
    (SELECT ISNULL(sum(ch.duration),0) from EXT_Workpackage ch where ch.Parent_Workpackage_ID=wp.ext_workpackage_id and ch.ext_workpackage_status_id not in (3,13)) [PWP_Planned],

    ISNULL(tah.hrs,0) [ActualHours],
    (select CONVERT(varchar,count(*)) from EXT_Workpackage wx where wx.Parent_Workpackage_ID=wp.ext_workpackage_id and wx.EXT_Workpackage_Status_ID in (2)) [WPLive],
    (select CONVERT(varchar,count(*)) from EXT_Workpackage wx where wx.Parent_Workpackage_ID=wp.ext_workpackage_id and wx.EXT_Workpackage_Status_ID in (1,2,5,7,8,12)) + ' / ' +
    (select CONVERT(varchar,count(*)) from EXT_Workpackage wx where wx.Parent_Workpackage_ID=wp.ext_workpackage_id and wx.EXT_Workpackage_Status_ID in (2)) [WPsCountLive],

    (SELECT ISNULL(sum(ch.Material_Cost),0) from EXT_Workpackage ch where ch.Parent_Workpackage_ID=wp.ext_workpackage_id) [PlannedChildMaterials],
    ISNULL(wp.Material_Cost,0) [PlannedMaterials],
    (SELECT TOP 1 Workpackage_Code FROM EXT_Workpackage WHERE Parent_Workpackage_ID = tah.Parent_Workpackage_ID AND Parent_Workpackage_ID IS NOT NULL) [Parent_Workpackage_Code],




    CASE
        WHEN wps.completed=1 THEN 1
        WHEN wps.completed = 0 THEN 0
    END [workpackage/@iscomplete]
    --(SELECT TOP 1 Workpackage_Code FROM EXT_Workpackage WHERE EXT_Workpackage_ID = wp.Parent_Workpackage_ID) AS [Parent_Workpackage_Code]
    from EXT_Workpackage AS wp
    LEFT JOIN Project p on wp.Project_ID=p.Project_ID
    LEFT JOIN EXT_Workpackage_Status wps on wp.EXT_Workpackage_Status_ID=wps.EXT_Workpackage_Status_ID
    LEFT JOIN EXT_Workpackage_Contract_Type wpc on wp.EXT_Workpackage_Contract_Type_ID=wpc.EXT_Workpackage_Contract_Type_ID
    LEFT JOIN EXT_Workpackage_Type wpt on wp.EXT_Workpackage_Type_ID=wpt.EXT_Workpackage_Type_ID
    LEFT JOIN #tempactualhoursb tah on wp.EXT_Workpackage_ID=tah.ext_workpackage_id
    LEFT JOIN EXT_Workpackage_Billing_Type b on wp.Billing=b.EXT_Workpackage_Billing_Type_ID
    --CROSS APPLY   [dbo].[EXT_FN_Parent_Workpackage_Code] (#tempactualhoursb.Parent_Workpackage_ID) PWC ON wp.EXT_Workpackage_ID = PWC.EXT_Workpackage_ID 
    where wp.Project_ID=868

    --AND Parent_Workpackage_Code IS NOT NULL

    order by wp.Workpackage_Code
```

Comment: Can you show sample data from each `Select` and expected results?

Comment: You have several issues in your code. Using subqueries as a scalar value is generally an indication that something is not quite right. That can usually be handled more cleanly. You also are converting to varchar but don't specify the length. This is a bad practice. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length You also have top 1 but no order by. Without an order by you can't determine which row will be returned.

Comment: To get real assistance you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are your hierarchical records self-parenting? Shouldn't the subquery joining `EXT_Workpackage.Parent_Workpackage_ID=tah.Parent_Workpackage_ID` instead be joining `EXT_Workpackage.EXT_Workpackage_ID=tah.Parent_Workpackage_ID`.